# Combining children with responsive markers ( [&>h1]:lg:text-lg )

Tags: tailwind-css

I recently learned about this way of targeting specific ( or all ) children in a container: `[&>h1]:text-sm`. This should make all `<h1>` elements in the parent with the `text-sm`. **Which works**.

Now I need a specific case where I can't target the element ( h1 ) itself, since it's coming from a variable in Laravel blade, so I want to target specific children from the parent. It does not register when I try any of these possibilities:

`[&>h1]:lg:text-lg`
`[&>lg:h1]:text-lg`
`lg:[&>h1]:text-lg`

What happens with the complete code is that the `<h1>` is `text-sm` on all screen sizes.. It does not register for the bigger font-sizes on md and lg.
ex: `[&>h1]:text-sm [&>h1]:md:text-md [&>h1]:lg:text-lg`

Answer (score 0):

The exact structure you should use would be `lg:[&>*>h1]:text-3xl`. To illustrate this, I have prepared a demo for you. You can control the font size by enlarging the screen. If your h1 tags are not a quadratic child, it will be sufficient to use the `[&>*]` structure directly. To access all h1 tags in a div regardless of their position, it will be sufficient to use the `[&_h1]` structure.

[Child selector demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RxpYqH1eR4)